# Multiple transformer windings vs a single winding with a buck converter for dual output power supply?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, noise, buck

I have to create a power supply that has both a 5V output at 1A and a 3.3V output at 0.4A. I was wondering if I should add another winding to my transformer or just make a 5V 1.5A power supply, and then use a [small buck converter](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv62568a.pdf?ts=1603208762159) to drop down the voltage to 3.3V.

I would think using a buck converter is both cheaper and easier, however I am a little worried about the noise adding a high frequency switching component will induce to the circuit.

So I would like to know, which option is cheaper, and will noise become a significant issue if I go with a buck converter?

Additional information: Flyback topology, switched mode power supply.

Comment: Unless you have an unusual application you should probably not be building a linear power supply (eg with a mains frequency transformer) today at all...

Comment: What's your requirement on cross regulation?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>In this answer I'm assuming that the basic circuit is a flyback converter that regulates to produce a 5 volt DC output. A regular old-fashioned power transformer cannot be relied upon to produce a stable 5 volt output due to the transformer's input AC voltage changing and because of its inability to provide decent regulation against load current changes.</sub>

The cheaper option is to have an extra winding, rectifier and smoothing capacitor but only by a few cents I suspect. You have to offset the extra few cents you might pay for a buck converter with the extra performance in terms of regulation you get from it when sharing one winding.

This is because only one transformer winding (in a flyback design presumably) can be regulated and the others follow suite. You might find that a heavy load on the 5 volts will increase the DC voltage on the rectified outputs of other windings and this may be a step too far - of course with one winding on the flyback transformer you can use the PWM to regulate it to 5 volts and, if you tee-off to another regulator there's no worries about that producing a stable output because it is a regulator.

It's unlikely that an extra buck converter on the 5 volt DC output from a flyback circuit will cause much of a problem but, I'm generalizing and the devil is in the detail so I can't guarantee this.

Comment: Thank you so much Andy, your answer is well received. You are correct in your assumption that it is coming from a flyback converter.

Comment: @willieb3 I've rejected your edit suggestion (please don't be sad LOL) because I can't see that it brings anything to the party.

Comment: No problem! I was trying to edit my own post and had not realized I accidentally selected yours.

Comment: @willieb3 if we are done on this old question you should mark it as "accepted" else raise another query on comment. [Take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand why folk give their time for free to help others.